# Groupby A column and bring up the A value, only if the B values differ from the other ones, including nulls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this example, dataset:

```
 A   B 
11   A
11   V
11   C
12   A
12   A
12   A
12   A
13   A
13   A
13   B
13   B
14   C
14   C
14   
14
```

And I want it to return, the grouped A values, that has different values on the B column. So in this example, the expected output is:

```
[11, 13,14]
```

I made an attempt at formulating the code, and I succeeded but it is terrible and  unoptimized. And I was looking for alternatives so I could iterate faster through my much bigger dataset. Would appreciate some help.

Here is my code:

```
user_mult_camps = []

for i in  df['A'].unique():
    filt = (df['A'] == i)
    df2 = df.loc[filt]
    x=df2['B'].unique()
    if len(x) > 1:
        user_mult_camps.append(i)
        print(i)
```

Comment: What should happen if you had a group with A/A/B ? Can you also provide the expected output?

Comment: Okay  i am insert it, but i want it to return to. Anything in the grouped b that is beyond 1 is appended you could say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `groupby` "A" and use `nunique` to count the number of unique "B"s per "A". Then evaluate if it's greater than 1 to filter the "A"s that have more than one corresponding "B":

```
msk = df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()>1
out = msk.index[msk].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[11]
```

If you want to count NaN as well, then set `dropna` parameter in `nunique` to False:

```
df2['B'] = df2['B'].fillna(value=np.nan)
msk = df2.groupby('A')['B'].nunique(dropna=False)>1
```

Then the output:

```
[11, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
out = df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique().pipe(lambda x: x[x > 1].index.to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([11])

>>> out[0]
11
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to ensure all values are different?

You could use:

```
s = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda s: ~s.duplicated().any())

s[s].index.tolist()
```

Output: `[11]`